# Creating a form page with java

Tags: javascript, html

Noob here again. I have a div id setup and the following code works for the one instance, but I need to have when they click static 3 forms areas aren't hidden any more. I know its a for loop, but I can't get they syntax right.

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Protocols(val){
var element=document.getElementById('static_ip')
 if(val=='pick a protocol'||val !='Static')
   element.style.display='none';
 else
   element.style.display='block';
}
</script>
```

---

Comment: Where is the Java? Java is not short for JavaScript.

Comment: So use something like querySelectorAll and select multiple elements and loop over them.

Comment: You could improve the question by providing the html for all 3 elements you need to show

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example, using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
function Protocols(val){
    const hideOrShow = document.querySelectorAll('#static_ip, #id2, #id3')
    for (element of hideOrShow) {
       if (val !== 'Static') {
           element.style.display = 'none';
       } else {
           // resetting to empty string falls back to default value
           element.style.display = '';
       }
   }
}
```

The Document method querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, Its working now. Thanks for the help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Protocols(val){
var element=document.querySelectorAll('#static_ip')
for ( i=0; i < element.length; i++) {
if(val=='pick a protocol'||val !='Static'){
element[i].style.display='none';
} else {
element[i].style.display='block';
}
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: it's bad practice to have more than one element with the same id